# How to override single property field in collection element using profile properties in spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have configuration that contains list of nested elements class like this

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my")
@Data
class MyConfig{

   ////some fields

   private List<InnerElement> inner;
}
```

And inner have some properties

```
@Data
class InnerElement{
    private String prop1;
    private String prop2;
    private String prop3;
}
```

`application.properties` contains example defaults like

```
my.inner[0].prop1=SomeA;
my.inner[0].prop2=SomeB;
my.inner[0].prop3=SomeC;
```

This works fine so far. However I need to change only single element of nested object in array using profile, so `application-myprofile.properties` looks like

```
my.inner[0].prop2=MY CUSTOM VALUE HERE
```

but that fails with the messaage that `prop1` and `prop2` are left unbound.

How to get rid of that error and make element 0 of `inner` to have overriden value of `prop2` ?? My expectations are that `inner[0]` will have

```
prop1=SomeA
prop2=MY CUSTOM VALUE HERE
prop3=SomeC
```

PS. I would like to avoid overriding whole element.

Comment: Ans are you using Spring Boot to load the properties or are you shoehorning it into another `@PropertySource` thing. ?

Comment: SpringBoot as is.

Comment: Please show how you start the software and please include sme configuration. Basically it should work, so you must be doing something other then the default. Also please specify **which version** of Spring Boot you are using.

Comment: Autoconfig doesn't work like that, it only checks top level variables, so there is no way using `@ConfigurationProperties`. It sees `MyConfig.inner[0]` exists and has been defined by `myprofile` properties  and will not bother to look in default for nested properties within the class.

Comment: Proprietary software, cannot share - but I will try to prepare demo project. Spring boot version 2.0.9.RELEASE - runs with java -jar

Comment: @123 this is only partially true - as I can override ALL properties of `inner[0]` via profile - but I would expect it to  "merge" and accept only single change

Comment: @Antoniossss That's what I am saying `inner[0]` is a top level variable, so a new instance is created by overriding profiles. The nested properties e.g `inner[0].prop3` are not checked when determining whether to use default values from application.properties as spring see that `inner[0]` has been set.

Comment: Ah ok, than yes that is what is happening now. Is there a way to plugin in myself into the process of creation? As for me it would be beneficial to tweak properties in a way that Map<String,String> is created and that is used for bean creation - in such way there would be no problem as corresponding line would be simply overriden in that map. Where to start? Im unfamiliar with Spring internals.

Comment: @Antoniossss You could have a look in the `org.springframework.boot.properties` package. Specifically line 89 (around there anyway depending on spring version) in `ConfigurationPropertiesBinder` could be a good place to start.